# How do I refer to properties of object array inside jagged array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, properties, jagged-arrays

this question is probably going to be a bit confusing, as I'm just starting c# and object-oriented coding in general, but I'll do my best to explain things clearly! For context, I'm trying to make a random dungeon generator for a game project.

I have the jagged array "Dungeon," which I've declared like this:

```
public Level[][,] Dungeon;
```

To clarify, Dungeon is a 1D array of "Levels." A level is its own object, and it has a few unique properties that I defined in its constructor.

Each level is a 2D array of "mazePieces," which are also objects.

I've figured out how to refer to the entire Dungeon array to do things such as see how many levels are in the dungeon:

```
Dungeon[x].Length
```

I also can refer to individual mazePieces in a given level:

```
Dungeon[i][x,y].mobAmount
```

However, I can't figure out how to refer to the properties of an entire Level. If I type in

```
Dungeon[i].numberOfRooms
```

"numberOfRooms" is not recognized as a property of the level. However, I've found that it will be recognized if I type

```
Dungeon[i][,].numberOfRooms
```

The issue I'm running into is that the second set of brackets are marked with a syntax error, saying that a value is expected.

What can I put into the second set of brackets so I can refer to the entire level rather than just a specific part of the level?

Hopefully this was at least somewhat understandable, please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify! Thanks!

Comment: you will have to loop through all of the elements to get the whole collection of properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone! I had a friend take a look at it and I realized I don't actually need a jagged array -- Each Level object contains an array so Dungeon just needs to be a 1D array, not a jagged. I guess I was either over thinking things or not really understanding the whole concept of objects yet. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that pieces of maze should be a part of `Level` class,

So you would have

```
public Levels[] Dungeon.
```

Also your `Level` class would have indexer:

```
public SomeReturnType this[int x, int y]
{
   get
   {
      // return maze piece
   }
}
```

In this case you would be able to access to any level property via `Dungeon[i].numberOfRooms`. And you still would be able to access to maze pieces like you want `Dungeon[i][x,y].mobAmount`

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, and I eventually did figure it out! I just had the wrong syntax -- I actually just needed a 1D array of levels, not a jagged array, as each level object already contained a 2D array of mazepieces. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a little more composition in your design. Maybe something like this:

```
class Dungeon {
    public Level[] Levels { get; private set; }

class Level {
    public int NumberOfRooms
        { get { return Maze.GetUpperBound(0) * Maze.GetUpperBound(1); }
    public MazePiece[,] Maze { get; private set; }
}

class MazePiece {
    private List<Mob> _mobs = new List<Mob>();
    public IEnumerable<Mob> Mobs { get { return _mobs; } }
    public int MobCount { get { return _mobs.Count; } }
}

class Mob {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can more naturally refer to things:

```
var mobsAtTenTenOfLevelThree = dungeon.Levels[2].Maze[9, 9].Mobs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `numberOfRooms` is a property of `MazePiece`, if you want to find a *total* for the dungeon you can use `SelectMany`:

```
int totalRooms = dungeon.SelectMany(p=>p.numberOfRooms).Sum();
```